# Bash list directories that matches pattern, not children of them

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a folder ~/anna which contains the file ~/anna/b

When I type ls ~/a* I get b.

How can I retrieve ~/anna ?

The script for recreating the scenatrio:

```
cd ~/
mkdir anna
touch anna/b
ls ~/a*
```

Expected result: anna

Actually result: b

Thanks!

Comment: `ls -d ~/a*` should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get help for the `ls`, just ask for it:

```
ls --help
```

You'll get list of useful options for the `ls` command, one of them:

> `-d`, `--directory`            list **directory** entries instead of contents,
>                                  and do not dereference symbolic links

So the solution (as stated in comments) would be:

```
ls -d ~/a*
```

Comment: this is might not be exactly that the OP wants; this will also show files starting with `a`. the `-d` flag means that the contents of directories should not be shown, but their name instead. It does not exclude files

Comment: The solution to @ChrisMaes's problem, is ``ls -d a*/``. The fix is here already in the glob, experiment with ``touch aaaa; echo a*/`` to see what the glob (shell filename expansion) does. If you need ``ls`` because of some options, you instruct with ``-d`` that it should not descend into the subdirectory. (``ls directory`` would show the contents of ``directory``.)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your different requirements, `find` might be more appropriate:

```
find ~/ -name "a*" -type d
```

or

```
find ~/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name "a*" -type d
```

explanation:

- `~/`: search in home dir
- `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`: only directories "one deep"
- `-name "a*"`: all files or folders starting with `a`
- `-type d`: find only directories